# elasticsearch query string search by amount(double)

Tags: elasticsearch

can you advise what index to put on the amount to search for this query?

```
                    query_string: {
                      query: searchKey,
                      fields: [
                        'comment',
                        'from_user_name',
                        'to_user_name',
                        'payment_code',
                        'from.account',
                        'from.account',
                        'to.account',
                        'amount',
                      ],
                      lenient: true,
                      default_operator: 'AND',
                      allow_leading_wildcard: false,
                      analyze_wildcard: true,
                    }
```

es version: 6.4.3

Comment: Please provide more details. your mappings for example. what is the issue? what have you tried so far?

Comment: ```{
  "transactions": {
    "mappings": {
      "transaction": {
        "amount": {
          "type": "double"
        },
....
      }
    }
  }
}
```